Fib tool script
Most of what I'm looking at having done, is in this video https://screenrec.com/share/K3B5P1wx9O but to make the limits of writing some text I'll write a bit more. I'm wanting to modify the fib tool on TV that allows pending orders to be place on my trade platform using pineconnector to do this.
Plus money management built in so proper risk management is needed.
please watch the video to get a better understanding with visual aids.
This is my 1st place posting this message
